# Visual Studio 2022 Publish window warning me about Azure App Service not supporting Win-x64

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-appservice

I have an ASP .Net 6 Web API (C#) which I am deploying to Azure App Service. On Visual Studio 2022's Publish window, I have the following configuration:

[image]

As you can see, there is a warning triangle next to the "Target Runtime" dropdown. If I hover my mouse over it, it says:

> The instance of Azure App Service you are deploying to does not
> support 'win-x64'. Please either enable support through Azure App
> Service's settings or pick a different target runtime.

Now, on my Azure App Service configuration, I do have it set to 64 Bit:

[image]

The API does work once deployed, so I'm not sure if it's maybe just a false alarm?

The App Service is on an S1:1 pay-as-you-go service plan, with Windows OS, and the location is South Africa North:

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.1.5

Thanks

Comment: actually I always keep the default setting in VS when I publish to azure app service. And the default option is `Portable`... Try it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TinyWang. In Visual Studio 2022's publish window, in the Deployment Method dropdown, I only have two options: Framework-dependent and Self-contained. The default I think was Framework-dependent, but when I upgraded to .Net 6 (from .Net 5) - about 2 months ago - it stopped working, so I had to switch to Self-contained. It's been working just fine like that, but this morning I noticed that warning (not sure how long it's been warning me for - but I only noticed it today)

Comment: By the way, it may take some time to make the change update to your VS client.. You can also try to delete the publish configuaration and create a new one...

Comment: About your `switch to Self-contained`, I think it may result from the runtime you chose when you create your azure web app, since you had a upgrading from .net 5 to 6, I'm afraid you also changed the setting of your azure web app, and I think it may took some time to take effect, so in your VS publish window will appear warning triangle. It's better to delete the old publish setting and recreate it. It also suitable for your changing on 32bit/64bit

Comment: Any progress sir?

Comment: Recreating the publish configuration made the warning go away. Thanks @TinyWang

Comment: that's fine, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by @TinyWang, I deleted and recreated the publish configuration, and the warning went away. Thanks